# How do I disable SSL/TLS certificate verification in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, ssl, certificate, tls, rtmp

I was going to write out a long drawn-out question with tons of details about my circumstance, but figured even though questions are usually much more detailed on here, this one is pretty simple (although I can't seem to find an answer for it after hours of Googling):

**How do I disable certificate verification in ffmpeg for streaming to an RTMPS server?**

i.e. I want to trust any certificate, regardless of its validity, without throwing a *TLS fatal alert.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-tls_verify 0` before the output URL.

Comment: Thank you! Marked this as correct because it answered my question and seems correct after Googling the option (plus I think it's fair to say that you would definitely know what you're talking about), but it appears that I was wrong about what to ask since I'm still getting a "TLS fatal alert". Back to the drawing board I go lol. Thank you for all the work you do for ffmpeg Windows, I always opt for the Gyan releases when upgrading since I've had much better luck with your binaries (although it's probably user error on my part tbf lol)